# kubernetes UI fails to get node stats (503)

Tags: kubernetes

I just started up the kube-ui cluster add-on, and it is having no problem getting information about what pods/services/etc are on the cluster from the master, but when it tries to proxy requests through the master to the nodes to get their status it fails with a 503 error.

```
Remote Address:x.x.x.x:443   <-- Kubernetes Master IP
Request URL:https://kube-master/api/v1/proxy/nodes/x.x.x.y:4194/api/v1.0/machine
Request Method:GET
Status Code:503 Service Unavailable
```

Is there some service I have to run on all the workers that I'm not aware of? For context, I'm also running the heapster / influx / grafana addon to capture cluster data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that cadvisor was not running on the nodes. So I added it to my cloud config and made sure docker opened port 4194 on the node.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. To view the node information, you may use the link `https://<master-ip>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui/#/dashboard/nodes/<node-name>` (kube-ui) or `https://<master-ip>/api/v1/nodes/<node-name>`.